# kuberentes nginx ingress websocket 502 error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

```yaml
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: xxx
  namespace: bob
  annotations:
    rancher.io/globalDNS.hostname: api-v2-xxx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: 3600
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: 3600
    nginx.org/location-snippets: |
      proxy_set_header HOST $host;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_http_version 1.0;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
spec:
  rules:
    - host: api-v2-xxx.microsoft.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: xxx
              servicePort: xxx-api-port
          - path: /ws/
            backend:
              serviceName: xxx
              servicePort: xxx-ws-port

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: xxx
  namespace: bob
spec:
  selector:
    com.microsoft/application.name: xxx
  ports:
    - name: xxx-api-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3010
    - name: xxx-ws-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 81
      targetPort: 31255
```

I'm trying to get the websocket that runs on port `31255` to work but all I get is 502 error. The `nginx.org/location-snippets` is the snippet I use successfully in a different server deployment where everything works fine.

I check the docker, everything is running fine, port is exposed, k8s service is forwarding the port the only problem is the ingress. I also tried 2 paths on a single URL, same result: /api/ works, /ws/ doesn't

The API port works, the websocket doesn't.

Comment: When you target your pod's ip directly on port 31255 do you get an expected response? `curl <pod-ip>:31255` Also, when you exec into the pod and try to access it do you get an expected response? `curl localhost:31255`

Comment: @Howard_Roark it works fine. I also use the exact same setup with docker-compose on a single instance (without Kubernetes) and with nginx configs made by me and everything works fine. any ideas?

Comment: I would try to simplify things and change the ingress rules to only route to `/ws` temporarily and see if it works and go from there.  I'd also look at your nginx logs to see if you see any requests destined for `/ws` making it there.

Comment: That's where I started, with clean and simple configs. Nginx Logs aren't saying anything. It's not reaching the Nginx in the docker

Comment: Is your ingress service behind a Load Balancer?

Comment: Yes @EduardoBaitello. I have other APIs and front-ends and they all work great. Everything except the websocket

Comment: Which type of Load Balancer are you using? Can you check if it supports Websockets? (For example, the AWS ELB only works with Websockets if you are using Layer 3 [TCP/SSL] listeners).

Comment: Nginx ingress on Rancher server. Cluster is set up on EC2 instances. It should, it's the default Nginx ingress @EduardoBaitello and there are references to websockets in the docs, just no clear solution